# How to open a custom screen from a GI made from that custom screen DAC

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom screen and two DACs (header and detail) that feed that custom screen.  We also have a GI that is based on the values in the detail DAC.  The custom screen's header has two key values.  What we'd like to be able to do is use one of the fields of the GI as a hyperlink to open our custom screen, passing two of the values from the GI into the Header's key fields.  I'd like to know if this is possible.

I understand how to create a new graph object for my custom screen in a graph extension and create a button to make a hyperlink, but since the GI doesn't have any graph to extend, it's a bit of a mystery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the required behavior is only achievable since ver. 6, where in the Generic Inquiry Designer you have the Navigation tab to configure how values from the GI will be passed into the Header's key fields:

[image]